# How to display grid on plot in sympy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I would like to display a grid with a plot using Sympy:

```
import sympy
from sympy import sin
from sympy.abc import x
from math import pi
sympy.plot(sin(x),xlim=(0,2*pi))
```

[image: Plot using Sympy]

Using matplotlib it is straight forward to add a grid :

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image: Grid using matplotlib]

How can I do this with Sympy?

Comment: Anyone knows if this is implemented with Sympy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since SymPy uses matplotlib under the hood if you have it available,
you can use:

```
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')
```

And that will style your sympy.plot()

To print all available styles, use:

```
import matplotlib as plt
print(plt.style.available)
```

Here's [a link about style](https://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html) for matplotlib

Answer (score 2):

Please add this.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
sns.set_style("whitegrid", {'grid.linestyle': '--'})
```

You can get fig like this: [image]

```
import sympy
from sympy import sin
from sympy.abc import x
from math import pi
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
sns.set_style("whitegrid", {'grid.linestyle': '--'})

sympy.plot(sin(x),xlim=(0,2*pi))
```